# How to 'insert if not exists' in php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I started by googling, and found this article which talks about mutex tables.

I have a table with ~14 million records. If I want to add more data in the same format, is there a way to ensure the record I want to insert does not already exist without using a pair of queries (ie, one query to check and one to insert is the result set is empty)?

Does a unique constraint on a field guarantee the insert will fail if it's already there?

It seems that with merely a constraint, when I issue the insert via php, the script croaks.

Comment: Define: "The script croaks"

Comment: You should turn your logic around. MySQL has a functionality to update if a record exist. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html You can use that to avoid insert duplicate records. Yes you do need a unique field in the records.

Answer (score 6):

> Does a unique constraint on a field guarantee the insert will fail if it's already there?

The unique constraints are enforced when inserting new data. If you try and insert data into a table that already has data, you should get an error like below:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'john-doe-(408)-999-9765' for key 'idx_name_phone'
```

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to simply ignore the insert on the duplicate rows (The error is essentially turned to a warning), or use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the row instead of inserting a new one. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) for more information.